# Symfony2: How to extend a Bundle?

Tags: symfony, bundle, extend

If i have `AlphaBunde` that is parent of `BetaBundle` how can i extend a twig block without overriding the entire template?

How can i import the routes that exist only in `BetaBundle`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot extend a block in Twig. You can overload it if you extend a template (and call parent() which kind of works as inheritance).

If you extend bundle you can overload its controllers or resources. I don't think you can really extend a template from a parent bundle because of how the paths are resolved. You can read more about it in the [Extending a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/quick_tour/the_architecture.html#extending-a-bundle) documentation chapter.

Also, [How to use Bundle Inheritance to Override parts of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-translations-validation-etc) might clarify few things.

Remember to check [Overriding Bundle Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates) to learn how to overload templates in an application.

About routes: I think you'll have to define each route in your application's configuration file if you want to import them selectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use template from another bundle and you do not want to override whole template you use this:

```
// Your file in ProjectAplhaBundle index.html.twig

{% extends "ProjectBetaBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ parent() }}
    Somethings added to the existing content    
{% endblock %}
```

For routing from just BetaBundle remove all routes (routing.yml in app folder) and leave just one with something like this:

```
ProjectBetaBundle:
    resource: "@ProjectBetaBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Then you specify all your routes in @ProjectBetaBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

I hope that helps. Cheers

Comment: i know that normally i can use these commands, but my `BetaBundle` has a `getParent()` function, and i can't use 
`{% extend "AlphaBundle::layout.html.twig" %}` 
in `BetaBundle` because it generate a loop.