# Symfony FosUserBundle extend from my default template from another bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.2

On my symfony 3.2 project I am using the `FOSUserBundle` for User Registration and authentication. What I am trying to do is to apply a custom theme to the registration form.

Therefore I have made the `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig` that is my application's base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        {% block stylesheets %}
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')}}" ></link>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/vendor/adminlte/adminlte.css')}}" ></link>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/vendor/adminlte/skin-blue.css')}}" ></link>
        {% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />

        {% block javascriptsHeader %}

        {% endblock %}

    </head>
    <body class="{{ classes }}">
      {% block body %}
      {% endblock body %}

      {% block javascriptsFooter %}

      {% endblock javascriptsFooter %}
   </body>
</html>
```

I have also changed `Resources/FOSUSerBundle/views/layout.html.twig` with the following content:

```
{% extends AppBundle::base.html.twig %}

{% body %}
  {% block fos_user_content %}
  {% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock body %}
```

As seen on:
* [Symfony2: How to extend a Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021367/symfony2-how-to-extend-a-bundle) 
* http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html

But I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of statement block" expected).
```

Do you have any idea how to use my default template as registration from template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong string in `extends`. Change

```
{% extends AppBundle::base.html.twig %}
```

to

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
```

and it should work.

NOTE: Using `::base.html` means that the template engine will look for `base.html` in `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig`. Setting `AppBundle::base.html.twig` is wrong. If the template was located in a bundle (i.e. `AppBundle` - `src/AppBundle`), then the path would look something like 
 `@AppBundle/base.html.twig`.